# Finding the direction of Array.sort, with context

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I would like to find the direction of an item, given it's sort value. However, I've discovered that `index` alone cannot accomplish what I want.

Given a sort function, I only want to find out if an item has actually moved to a different index based on it's value and not because another item was moved.

Example:

```
const things = [
  { id: 't1', val: 4 }, // This moves to index 1, see T1 notes
  { id: 't2', val: 2 },
  { id: 't3', val: 5 }, // This moves to index 0
  { id: 't4', val: 1 },
  { id: 't5', val: 3 },
]

// Sort to highest vals first
let thingOrder = things.sort((a, b) => b.val - a.val)

thingOrder = thingOrder.map((thing, index) => {
  const oldIndex = things.indexOf(thing)

  if (index === oldIndex)
    thing.direction = 'same'
  else if (index > oldIndex)
    thing.direction = 'up'
  else if (index < oldIndex)
    thing.direction = 'down'

  return thing
})

console.log(thingOrder)
```

Expected result:

```
{ id: 't3', val: 5 }, // Up
{ id: 't1', val: 4 }, // Same
{ id: 't5', val: 3 }, // Same
{ id: 't2', val: 2 }, // Down
{ id: 't4', val: 1 }, // Down
```

T1 notes: Technically the item with id `t1` has moved to index 1, but not because of it's `val` - but because T3 has moved above it.

How can I accomplish the goal of discovering whether an item has truly moved up or down in the list?

Comment: _"Technically the item with id `t1` has moved to index 1, but not because of it's  val - but because `t3` has moved above it"_. That's not true, both of them moved because of their values, otherwise, it would've stayed there.

Comment: I understand it's not TECHNICALLY true. All items are reindexed via .sort. I hope you understand what I mean and try not to be too nit-picky. ;)

Comment: Why do you need this, might I ask?

Comment: I need to discover whether items have gone up or down via streaming data. One example is something for sorting comment likes.

Comment: Another example are for things like stock tickers. Sky is the limit.

Comment: The only way you'll know is if you're implementing your own sorting function, otherwise it won't be clear whether it's `t3` that affected the position of `t1` and `t2`, or it was `t1` and `t2` that affected the position of `t3`

Comment: Do you have an example of how to accomplish this via a custom sort function?

Comment: Do you have a sort function?

Comment: `let thingOrder = things.sort`

Comment: I meant one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), implemented from sctratch, that way you'll have control over the moving, so you can clearly tell which items moved using their values and which didn't.

Comment: That's why I'm on SO. Trying to wrap my head around such an algorithm. I don't mind trying to implement it myself. Just need a direction.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir is correct. You'll need to write one yourself and keep track of how things are moving around. The wikipedia article he linked links to a few different sorting algorithms, and these all have pseudocode you can follow to create your own. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: BTW, to clear my suspicion, do you want to tell **which items changed their position and which didn't, regardless of how they were moved**, or do you want to tell **which items changed position on their own only**?

Comment: It sounds like the former. That said, I'd need to know if their position was the result of other items being moved to above them. Or whether they truly have gone down in the list. It's difficult to conceptualize in my head. So it leans slightly on the latter too.

Comment: Why don't you just check if the value changed? if someone upvotes a comment, keep track of that comment score, sort, if the comment changed its index then you'll know it's because of its value.

Comment: Primarily because it's unorganized data being streamed from other resources. It's data that is decentralized and has a bunch of mutability gotchas. Although, I will think on this and see if I can approach the problem from a different angle.

Comment: `[{a: 5}, {b: 3}, {c: 3}]`, someone upvotes `c`, we record that `c`'s value has changed and that `a`'s and `b`'s remained the same (just copy of the old array will do), we sort, we get `[{a: 5}, {c: 4}, {b: 3}]`, we can clearly say that `c` moved on its own but `b` didn't

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments it looks like there is some discussion on what it means to move. I'm not sure what this means (even after the comments)

> Given a sort function, I only want to find out if an item has actually moved to a different index based on it's value and not because another item was moved

An item isn't moved based on its value. It's moved based on the relationship of its value to those around it.

But if you just want to compare where an item ends up starts from where it starts you can do this.
Make a range from zero to the length of the array. Then sort that based on the sort order of the array. This sorted range will show you which indexed when where.

```js
const things = [
    { id: 't1', val: 4 }, // This moves to index 1, see T1 notes
    { id: 't2', val: 2 },
    { id: 't3', val: 5 }, // This moves to index 0
    { id: 't4', val: 1 },
    { id: 't5', val: 3 },
  ]

// This is a simple range:
let sortOrder = Array.from(things, (_, i) => i)

// Sort it based on things
sortOrder.sort((a, b) => things[a].val - things[b].val )

console.log("sort order:", sortOrder)

// map to direction names
// by comparing index to current position
let directions = sortOrder.map((item, i) => {
    if (item > i) return "up"
    if (item < i) return "down"
    return "same"
})

console.log(directions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Mark's answer helped, it didn't quite get me there. I wanted to see whether an item was moving up or down, relative to other items.

The solution I ended up with is this:

```
const things = [
  { id: 't1', val: 4 }, // Expected: Same
  { id: 't2', val: 2 }, // Expected: Down
  { id: 't3', val: 5 }, // Expected: Up
  { id: 't4', val: 1 }, // Expected: Down
  { id: 't5', val: 3 }, // Expected: Same
]

let thingOrder = things.slice().sort((a, b) => b.val - a.val)

indexDiff = (thing, oldIndex) => {
 const newIndex = thingOrder.indexOf(thing)
 const indexDiff = oldIndex - newIndex

 return indexDiff
}

thingOrder = things.map((thing, oldIndex) => { 
  const indexDiffVal = indexDiff(thing, oldIndex)

  const targetIndexDiff = indexDiff(
    thingOrder[oldIndex],
    things.indexOf(thingOrder[oldIndex]
  ))

  const moveDistance = indexDiffVal + targetIndexDiff
  const moveDirectionSign = Math.sign(moveDistance)

  let moveDirection = 
        (moveDirectionSign === 1) ? 'up'
        : (moveDirectionSign === -1) ? 'down' 
        : (moveDirectionSign === 0) ? 'same'
        : (moveDirectionSign === -0) ? 'same'
        : 'same'

  moveDirection = (moveDistance === 1) ? 'same' : moveDirection

  thing.direction = moveDirection

  return thing
})

console.log(thingOrder)
```

These are the notes I took while trying to figure this formula out.

> ```
> indexDiff:
> t1 = 1i - 2i = -1d (down)
> t2 = 2i - 4i = -2d (down)
> t3 = 3i - 1i = 2d (up)
> t4 = 4i - 5i = -1d (down)
> t5 = 5i - 3i = 2d (up)
>
> Compare diffs of item[newIndex] to item[oldIndex]
> t1 = oldIndex = 1, t3 = newIndex = 1
> t1 = indexDiff(-1), t3 = indexDiff(2)
> -1 + 2 = [1] (didn't really move)
>
> t2 = oldIndex = 2, t1 = newIndex = 2
> t2 = indexDiff(-2), t1 = indexDiff(-1)
> -2 + -1 = [-3] (did move down)
>
> t3 = oldIndex = 3, t5 = newIndex = 3
> t3 = indexDiff(2), t5 = indexDiff(2)
> 2 + 2 = [4] (did move up)
>
> t4 = oldIndex = 4, t2 = newIndex = 4
> t4 = indexDiff(-1), t2 = indexDiff(-2)
> -1 + -2 = [-3] (did move down)
>
> t5 = oldIndex = 5, t4 = newIndex = 5
> t5 = indexDiff(2), t4 = indexDiff(-1)
> 2 + -1 = [1] (didn't really move)
> ```